# Package background autoupdater without using google play market without user interaction

Tags: android

My app not stored in google play, it is stored in my server. My device does not have google play market app. New versions of my app I put to my server. I want that my app would update in background automatically without user interaction. Is it possibble? I checked several links on stack regarding to this question, but I want to refresh it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this library here:

[Update Checker](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker)

Follow the steps and it works. I have used it in my application. As far as the user interaction is concerned, You can't update without user interaction if you have not rooted your device. Android does not allow you to install any application without permission else anybody would install many malicious applications in background.